# Is it possible to have two different EditorDrivers simultaneously editing the same object?

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

In my app, I have a presenter (`Presenter1`) which I use to kick off an Editor (`EditorView1`) which edits a `Foo` object. This MVP setup is akin to what is described in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699346/565863

Now, let's say that I need to create another view (`EditorView2` which is kicked off by `Presenter2`) which also edits a `Foo` object, but needs to make use of `EditorView1`.
`EditorView1` would be supplied to  `EditorView2` by `Presenter1`.

This approach seems sloppy and error prone. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I realized a much more clean approach.

The problem with what is described above is that I was intent on re-using the first Presenter, `Presenter1`.

It would be much cleaner to abstract out the Editor portion of the `EditorView1` code into a re-usable Editor widget (`Editor1`) which could be used by both `EditorView1` and `EditorView2`. Now, I have one presenter, one view, and one EditorDriver. There is no need to juggle nested presenters or multiple EditorDrivers.

Comment: You can close the question by choosing your own answer :)

Comment: I was waiting to see if someone might have had any input. But thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Besides, SO isn't letting me accept my own answer till tomorrow :)